# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

> As of 2021, the site is no longer under pro tem moderation. It is now under elected moderation. Donald.McLean stepped down, but called2voyage and HDE 226868 have stayed on as moderators. They were joined by an additional mod as a result of the [election here](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/723/6).

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: HDE 226868]
[image: Donald McLean]
[image: called2voyage]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Let's also thank these users, who have moderated in the past:

[image: RhysW]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/flair/96.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for accepting me! I look forward to being able to support this community further as a pro tem mod.

Comment: Congratulations to our new overlords...erm... I mean PT mods!!

Comment: Habemus moderatores!

Comment: Thank you very much Jon! I'm sure called2voyage and DonaldMc.Lean share my sentiments when I say we are honored to have been chosen to guide astronomy through its beta stage.

Comment: congratulations to all the pro tem mods. lets all together make our Astronomy SE a big success. All the best Mods.