# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Astronomy's first election has come to a close. We are delighted to appoint your new moderator:

[image: Connor Garcia]
He'll be joining the [existing crew](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).  Please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as he learn the ropes!

You can view the election history [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/election/1).

Comment: Congrats Connor, and my appreciation to all our moderators for the work you put in, most of it unseen by us. I do very much look forward to the day when we can welcome an additional moderator from some other part of Planet Earth: currently all three Earth-bound mods are from the USA, the other one hailing from "A small planet somewhere in the vicinity of Betelgeuse". ;-)

Comment: @Chappo You should probably consider putting that into an answer :)

Comment: @Chappo Also, maybe if humans colonize Mars or some other planet in the near future, maybe from there... ;)

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I'm also in the US - I use a very liberal definition of "vicinity". . .

Comment: @HDE226868 Is a star 600 ly from us still within our "neighbourhood", or would astronomers regard this as "out of town"?

Comment: @called2voyage This has been featured for about a month. When would it be a good time to remove it from the featured on Meta? Or maybe we still need to congratulate our new moderator more (I think so!)?

Comment: @fasterthanlight Featured tags automatically go away after awhile, so unless something comes up that we need that featured slot for, I'll probably just let it age out.

Answer (score 6):

## Congratulations, Connor Garcia!!!

I want to give a huge shoutout to @ConnorGarcia for having courage to self-nominate and take on a task that requires much time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Well done @ConnorGarcia . Without voluntary moderators there would be no Astronomy Stack exchange.